# Thinktecture Identity Server User Store

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, membership

I am new to Identity server but I found it quite easy to set up.

Our goal is to implement SSO down the line but at the moment we are just moving our authentication logic out of application.

It is going good except I have one confusion.

When I set up the Idsrv, I had to create admin user as well as token requesting user. This was to access and configure Idsrv.

For application auth, I have to use Idsrv as federation server as well and authenticate users against some Asp.Net data store.

Now there is already one data store where Identity server specific users are stored.

Should I be using same store for my application user auth and created/edit these users in that store? Or can I/should I create a separate database for application specific users and use both?

At the minute, I am authenticating application users against Idsrv store.

I am not sure if I am logically thinking in right way to split these two user sets and calling one as Idsrv specific users. (We will have Identity service separately deployed for each application)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Also, does Identity server needs to set up a specific role (name) for administration specific access on Idsrv?